# She is pregnant. vs She is going to have a baby

Tags: phrase-meaning

Am I right that the difference between

> She is pregnant.
>
> She is going to have a baby.

is as follows: the first one is about her current state, but the second one is about her decision to have a baby, keep this baby?

Comment: In most circumstances the second is simply a more 'polite' way to express the first. You can also say "She is expecting [a baby]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are mostly correct. "She is pregnant" means "She is pregnant." However, "She is going to have a baby" can mean any one or more of the following:

- She is pregnant.
- She will adopt a baby.
- She will get pregnant.
- She will not have an abortion.

In some communities or social situations talking about bodily functions is considered taboo or impolite, so saying "she is pregnant" *may* be considered rude, partly because of the implication that she has had sex; in that case saying "she is going to have a baby" is a politer way of saying "she is pregnant" and does not necessarily make a distinction between current state and future plans. But the other meanings are all possible.

Comment: I would have thought _She will not have an abortion_ would be expressed as _She is going to have/keep **the** baby_, it being understood that she is expecting one. (BTW _She is expecting [a baby]_ is another way to say it.)

Comment: @Kate, sure, that would be a more common way of saying it. Just pointing out how many things *could* be meant by "she is going to have a baby."

Comment: I would note that out of all of these, it *most likely* means "She is pregnant." If she were adopting, you would say that. If she's looking to get pregnant, she's not going to have a baby yet, and it would be a very weird way to word not having an abortion.